# Kubernetes Node Resets on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

We have Google Kubernetes cluster setup with 2 node pools , today we have noticed that the first node pool min node value has changed from 2 to 1 node , we have confirmed with our team and as per our discussion it has not been updated by our end , now we need to find out how this value has been changed, please help

```
1. node pool 1 - 
instance type - g1-small
min instance - 2 
auto scale - scale upto 5

2. node pool 2
instance type - n1-standard-1
min instance - 2 
auto scale - scale upto 3
```

Comment: that change should appear under Activity.

Comment: whether it was done by a user or by Google, the change to the node pool configuration will appear in stackdriver logs

Comment: Is there an autoscaling rule in play here?

Comment: We had setup auto scaling , it should scale upto 5 nodes in nodepool1 and we had set the min nodes to 2 , but after a few days later that value or the min node value in node pool 1 reset to 1 from 1, it was done by google end.I again set the min node value to 3 now in node pool 1 ,but after few mins later it again reset to 1.

Comment: found below logs
io.k8s.coordination.v1beta1.leases.update
io.k8s.core.v1.configmaps.update
io.k8s.coordination.v1beta1.leases.update
io.k8s.coordination.v1beta1.leases.update
io.k8s.core.v1.configmaps.update
io.k8s.coordination.v1beta1.leases.update
io.k8s.extensions.v1beta1.deployments.patch
io.k8s.coordination.v1beta1.leases.update
io.k8s.coordination.v1beta1.leases.update
io.k8s.core.v1.configmaps.update
io.k8s.coordination.v1beta1.leases.update
io.k8s.core.v1.configmaps.update
io.k8s.coordination.v1beta1.leases.update

Comment: This is really not an expected behavior, I believe the best would be to reach Google Cloud Support and ask for clarification, since this issue is specific to a managed feature, open your Cloud console, click the `(?)` question mark and select `get support` to reach GCP Support. I also encourage you to post an answer here after solving your issue if you think the solution would benefit the community.

Comment: we have already tried to get support from Google , but they said , since you don't have managed support plan so they can't help on it and asked us to submit a post on stackoverflow.com